# which plugin is needed to be installed to fix below error,

Tags: azure, packer

I am trying to execute following command, but coming up with following error
Please provide relvent software to install so that I will verify, thank you
packer build ubunthu.json

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To install this plugin, copy and paste this code into your Packer configuration, then run `packer init`.

```
packer {
  required_plugins {
    azure = {
      source  = "github.com/hashicorp/azure"
      version = "~> 2"
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use packer plugins install to manage installation of this plugin.

```
packer plugins install github.com/hashicorp/azure
```

https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/integrations/hashicorp/azure